# Problems Configuring Spring boot multi-module Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multi-module

I am having issues configuring spring boot multi module project!

This is my parent pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>main-module</module>
    <module>rabbit-mq-AOP</module>
   
  </modules>
  
  <dependencies>
        common dependencies..
  </dependencies>
```

In the module `rabbit-mq-AOP` I have only one configuration class for configuring rabbit MQ reading values from property file, AND I have added AOP for catching requests/responses of APIS.
It has no Repository or entity classes or controllers.

The configuration class looks like:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@Configuration
@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RabbitMQConfig { .... }
```

Note I have added exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` because, if I don't use this module in `rabbit-mq-AOP` it gives me Error when starting `main-module`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExistingValue must be an instance of com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

The base package in `rabbit-mq-AOP`  is `com.a.producer`.

The base package in `main-module` is `com.a.ds`.

This is the main class of module `main-module` from which i am trying to run

```
    @EnableSwagger2
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.a")
    public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer { .... }
```

With Above configuration, application does not startup and start giving error of `No qualifying bean of type` on repository classes of this module.

If I change this above main class to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.a.producer")`
the application will start up but no Controllers will be listed in the swagger of `main-module`, also the Apis will not work in-fact The rest Controllers are not recognized. The swagger-ui is detecting actuator api's which should be hidden as configured in properties file

[SWAGGER - UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vai3.png)

Note: With Spring logs as DEBUG Notice this specific line.

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

I am relying on DataSource Auto configuration of Spring by just adding the Jpa properties in property file not custom configuration class.
Guide a way around this as I have to use the module `rabbit-mq-AOP` in multiple projects and it will read the properties from where it is integrated i.e in this case from `main-module`

**Update**:

If I add these annotations on main class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.a.ds.repository")
@EntityScan("com.a.ds.dto.entity")
@ComponentScan("com.a.ds.config")
```

Again I get this Error which should not come now.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExistingValue must be an instance of com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem in two steps

1. Added these annonations

   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScans({ @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.a.ds.*")})
   @Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

on Configuration class in main-module

2. Created Database Configuration Class with two beans `dataSource` and `entityManagerFactory`